# google calendar iframe: "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Tags: html, iframe, calendar

> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

This shouldn't be it, because I've set my history settings to default.

There's also this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFOjF.png

Don't know if that'll help though.

I've tried it in my current browser (latest pale moon) and firefox 28 (yeah I know).

EDIT: FIXED IT! Turns out it had something to do with the cookie exceptions. Removed [www.google.com | Allow first party only], and now it works!

Comment: Some script? Please post your code

Comment: Right. Sorry.
    `<iframe class="iframe" src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=REMOVED%40gmail.com&ctz=Europe/Amsterdam" style="border: 0" height="512" scrolling="no"></iframe>`
Mostly the default embed code.

Comment: I have no clue.. For me it seems to be working. It might be your browser.

Comment: Weirdest part is that the page works fine when loaded in its own tab. (by the way, I've already tried restarting without addons, doesn't work - same with the removal of all google cookies)